# How can one edit the title of a dataset?

Tags: usaidopen

I need to 'standardize' the titles of several draft datasets for uniformity. How can I go about this? I can't seem to find a way in 'edit' mode. Thanks.

Comment: Did you download a dataset and want to change its name? Or are you a US government entity publishing its own data? What software or webapp are you using? Feel free to post screenshots if relevant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Only registered users with a DDL Editor account may edit their own dataset's metadata. Assuming that is the case for you, go to "Edit," "Edit Dataset Metadata" and locate the "Data Overview" tab. From there, you can edit the title of your dataset. Be sure to save your changes and resubmit to the platform.

MP